# Enhance performance while uploading multiple files

Tags: javascript, performance, file-upload, request

I'm trying to upload multiple images to server using Javascript. It works, however, the browser is stunned while uploading about 100 images.

Here are my codes:

Firstly, upload multiple files at once

```
uploadListImages(images) {
  images.forEach((image, index) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('image_file', image);
    formData.append('image_name', image.name);

    MyHttpRequestClass
      .myPOST(URL, formData)
      .then(respond => {

        // processing code

      })
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
  });
}
```

While uploading files with this, I have to wait for such a long time, the browser is nearly crashed (not responding message).

Then, I change to upload synchronously each images by recursion.

```
uploadListImages(images, recursiveIndex = 0) {
  if (recursiveIndex === images.length) {
    return;
  }

  const formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('image_file', images[recursiveIndex]);
  formData.append('image_name', images[recursiveIndex].name);

  MyHttpRequestClass
    .myPOST(URL, formData)
    .then(respond => {

      // processing code

    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err))
    .then(() => this.uploadListImages(images, recursiveIndex + 1));
}
```

The browser is no longer crashed, I can still scroll, or do other tasks, however, it is very slow. Do you have anyway to enhance this?

Comment: So one at once is too slow, but 100 at once is too fast. Try 5 at once? 10 at once? Something like that?

Comment: @CertainPerformance sorry, my fault, it is too slow while uploading about 100 images. Yes it is stunned with only 10 at once, but not for long.